# How many passes do bubble sort need?

Tags: algorithm, bubble-sort

How to check how many passes to sort the element in an array by using bubble sort? I already have the naive solution.

```
int count_the_pass(int *p,int size){
    int count;
    for(int i = 0;i<size-1;i++){
        bool flag = false;
        for(int j=0;j<size-i-1;j++){
            if(p[j]>p[j+1]){
                int temp = p[j];
                p[j] = p[j+1];
                p[j+1] = temp;
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        if(flag==false)
            return i;
    }
}
```

However this method only suitable for the array size is small enough(less than 3000). 
When the array size is big ,I got time limit exceed. How can I compute the number of passes more efficiency?

I also tried to count the inversion number of whole array.
But I can't figure out what's the relation of inversion number and the number of passes. 
Example:

> {1,3,4,2}    The inversion is {(3,2),(4,2)} and it need two passes.
>
> {1,4,2,3}    The inversion is {(4,2),(4,3)} and it need one pass.

Both of two examples have 2 inversion pairs, but the first need 2 passes to sort , the second need only one pass.

Comment: Hint: an element moves at most one place to the left per iteration.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem I got some idea about your hint i will try to implement the idea ,thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I already solve the problem thanks for your hint.